# Intuitive thought about infinities

Tags: infinity, infinite-groups

I've been thinking lately about Cantor's work on different 'sizes' of infinity. I really like the simple approach of Cantor's diagonal proof and have a certain way of thinking about it which I'd highly appreciate getting feedback on:

I imagine a set of all rational numbers & a parallel set of the exact same numbers, only they're added with, say, $\sqrt2$.

An illustration:
$(0,1,0.5,0.33333...)$ and $(0+\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2,0.5+\sqrt2,0.33333+\sqrt2...)$

So, as I see it, I have two identical sized sets. The first is an infinite set of all the rationals and the second is an infinite set of irrationals but only using $\sqrt2$ out of an infinite array of irrational combinations.

Now, it's possible to construct infinitely many more equal sets (+$\sqrt3$ set, + $\sqrt5$ set etc.) of irrational numbers.

Finally, my question is - is this a mathematically sound way of showing different cardinality between rational numbers and irrational numbers?

When I asked a friend whose doing his MA in math about it, he was deterred but couldn't quite explain if something is wrong about it.

Comment: Ok, I'm imagining these two sets, and they have the same size. What now?

Comment: But what is your question? You can take any irrational number, say transcendental $\pi$, and build a set of all natural or all rational numbers increased by $\pi$: $\{\pi+n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\{\pi+q : q\in\mathbb Q\}$, respectively. And what special property do you think those sets have?

Comment: What is your question? Is it "what cardinality does the union of those sets have?" (it's countable) or "does the latter set exist?" (yes, by axiom schema of separation) or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

The argument given doesn't prove that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb Q$.  It's kind of like if you provide an injection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ (for example, by mapping $n$ to $n + 1/3$) and then claim that it follows that $\mathbb Q$ has a larger cardinality than $\mathbb Z$.  Another way to look at it is that the argument given, if it were valid, would equally well show that the set of algebraic numbers is larger than $\mathbb Q$.  But that is false.

Comment: I just want to comment for amirshilo's benefit that even with $\mathbb{Q}$, you can do this infinitely many times to get infinitely many copies: $\mathbb{Z}+\frac12$, $\mathbb{Z}+\frac13$, .... Even still, $\mathbb{Q}$ has no greater cardinality than $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding roots doesn't get you very far because you are still in a number system denoted $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ including all algebraic numbers, which is still countable. You need to throw in transcendental (i.e., non-algebraic) numbers to get higher cardinality.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding.
the Question is - Is this a mathematically sound explanation of why there are infinitely many more irrationals than rationals?

Comment: @amirshilo Indeed, you have constructed an injection from Q to R\Q, which shows that the cardinality of Q is less than or equal to the cardinality of the set of irrational numbers. It's mathematically sound, but you still need a step to show that the cardinality is not equal.

Comment: Since, these two sets have the same cardinality, but there are obviously infinitely many more equally sized sets of different irrationals. (+√3 set, -√3 set etc..)
Makes sense ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that there are as many natural numbers as there are *even* natural numbers?

Comment: Yup.
This is about the difference between the amount of rationals and irrationals, and whether this is a good proof/way of showing it.

Comment: @amirshilo This may not work. Consider ZxZ, the Cartesian product of Z, it has infinitely many more "equally sized" sets of integers. But it has the same cardinality as Z.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but I assume you're trying to prove that the above two sets have the same cardinality. This is true. Two sets have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between them: $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q+\sqrt 2, \quad f:q\mapsto q+\sqrt 2$ does the job.